# VBA Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set Error (find all non-empty cell within specific column across all worksheets)

Tags: excel, vba

This is my Code

```
'Looping Each Worksheet and Check Whether They Are Project Tabs


    Dim ws As Worksheet                                          'Variable - Looping All Worksheets
    Dim wsName As String                                         'Variable - Get Worksheet Name


    Dim ReFCell_CostCode_Header As Range                         'Variable - Locate "Cost Code" Cell
    Dim ReFCell_CostCode_Letter As String                        'Variable - Get "Cost Code" Cell Letter
    Dim ReFCell_CostCode_ColAddress As String                    'Variable - Get "Cost Code" Cell Address

    Dim ReFCell_FirstCell_Address As String                       'Variable - Break Looping Within one Worksheet (FirstCell Address)

    Dim Cost_Code As Range                                        'Variable - Store CostCode Value

    Dim ProjectName As Range                                     'Variable - Save Project Name Value
    Dim StoreName As Range                                       'Variable - Save Store Name Value

    Dim i As Long                                                'Variable - Copy Cost Code to The Right Place

    i = 2

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        'Get Worksheet Name
        wsName = ws.Name
        
        'Check Tab's Name Contain #
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(ws.Name, 1, 1)) Then
            GoTo NextWorksheet

        'Locate Cost Code Header & Loop Each Indivisual Cost Code
        Else

            'Get Cost Code Header Column Address Within the Worksheet
            Set ReFCell_CostCode_Header = ws.UsedRange.Find("Cost Code", MatchCase:=True)
            ReFCell_CostCode_Letter = Split(ReFCell_CostCode_Header.Address, "$")(1)
            ReFCell_CostCode_ColAddress = ReFCell_CostCode_Letter & ":" & ReFCell_CostCode_Letter

            'Record The First Cost Code Item Address
            Set Cost_Code = ws.Range(ReFCell_CostCode_ColAddress).Find("*", after:=Range(ReFCell_CostCode_Header.Address))
            ReFCell_FirstCell_Address = Cost_Code.Address

            'Save Project Name & StoreName
            Set ProjectName = ws.UsedRange.Find("Project Name:", MatchCase:=True)
            Set StoreName = ws.UsedRange.Find("Store Name:", MatchCase:=True)

            Do
             
                'Cost Code
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 1).Value = Cost_Code
                'Vendor Name
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 2).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, -9)
                'Standard Contract Name
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 3).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, -6)
                'Standard Contract Amount
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 4).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, 2)
                'Approved Change Orders
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 5).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, 5)
                'Total Committed
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 6).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, 7)
                'Date
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 7).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, -4)
                'Invoiced
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 8).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, 10)
                'Balance Remaining
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 9).Value = Cost_Code.Offset(, 11)
                'Project Name
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 10).Value = ProjectName.Offset(, 1)
                'Store Name
                Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Cells(i, 11).Value = StoreName.Offset(, 1)
                
                Set Cost_Code = Worksheets(wsName).Range(ReFCell_CostCode_ColAddress).FindNext(Cost_Code)
                
                i = i + 1

            Loop While ReFCell_FirstCell_Address <> Cost_Code.Address

        End If
NextWorksheet:

    Next ws
```

The error pops out and it point to this line of code

[image]

I'm am expecting to loop all worksheets and the cost_code variable will always find all non-empty cell within each worksheet in a defined column range.

The data set is fine. I started with only one worksheet and the code worked out fine. for instance

Code:
`Set non_empty_cell = Worksheets("0002").Range(ref_col).FindNext(non_empty_cell)`

but it wouldn't work when i replace specific worksheet with a variable that represent worksheet name

Comment: `after:=Range(ReFCell_CostCode_Header.Address)` here `Range` needs to be `ws.Range`

Comment: Otherwise your loop looks fine, as long as you are not clearing values in `Cost_Code` it should always loop around and `Cost_Code` should always be a cell reference (assuming the first find succeeded, and if it hadn't you'd have gotten an error at `ReFCell_FirstCell_Address = Cost_Code.Address`)

Comment: VBA still pops out the same error message after i have changed the range to ws.range.

I set up a watch and it shows nothing for the find next(cost code)
The code can successfully find the item after the Cost Code header, but not the second even thought the second item is literally below the first one under the same column.

Comment: That works for me - as long as it finds the first match it should always loop, even if there were only one value in the column...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest skipping the `Find()` all together - it just adds complexity.  A simple loop over the column would be easier:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cost_Code As Range, ProjectName As Range, StoreName As Range
    Dim i As Long, ccHdr As Range, c As Range

    i = 2
    'Looping Each Worksheet and Check Whether They Are Project Tabs
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If ws.Name Like "#*" Then 'Check tab name begins with a digit
            'note not checking each of these calls to Find succeeds...
            Set ProjectName = ws.UsedRange.Find("Project Name:", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            Set StoreName = ws.UsedRange.Find("Store Name:", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            Set ccHdr = ws.UsedRange.Find("Cost Code", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            
            For Each c In ws.Range(ccHdr.Offset(1), _
                              ws.Cells(Rows.Count, ccHdr.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then 'has a value ?
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vendor DATA").Rows(i)
                        .Cells(1).Value = c.Value              'Cost Code
                        .Cells(2).Value = c.Offset(, -9).Value 'Vendor Name
                        .Cells(3).Value = c.Offset(, -6).Value 'Standard Contract Name
                        'etc etc
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next c
        End If 'is a worksheet we want
    Next ws
End Sub
```